# How to split a regular expression into parts?

Tags: regex

I need to break down a regular expression into its basic parts. For instance, given the regex `[a-d]+[r-z]*` I need to split it into `[a-d]+` and `[r-z]*`. This is of course a very simple example, and regex syntax can get very complex...

Is there a (relatively) simple way to achieve this, or am I doomed to reverse-engineer a regex parser?

<sub>I need this to find out if a given string is a part of matching input for a given regular expression.</sub>

Comment: Have you considered using a regex?  Can you show a more complicated example?

Comment: Possible [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Jongware, parsing regular expressions with regular expressions. [Will it blend](http://gizmodo.com/5690469/what-happens-when-you-blend-a-blendtec)?

Comment: My aim is not to verify that the given string is a regex. My aim is to use each regex part individually.

Comment: @Yuval, provide a motivation. Why do you need to parse regex? Do you really need it?

Comment: @Basilevs my task is to decide, given a string and a regex, if the string can be extended to match the regex. I'm trying to match the string to a part (or contiguous parts) of the regex.
Does that answer your question? Does it help future readers of this question?

Comment: @Yuval, how is the result of the test is used?

Comment: @Yuval I'm still unclear what the real use case here is... WHY do you want to extend a string to match a regex? Is this purely a technical challenge/exercise, or is this part of some application?

Comment: @TomLord Basilevs I appreciate the wish to be helpful with my task, but it is just an exercise, nothing interesting about it.

Comment: Then I would think very carefully about the rabbit hole you could be going down here, and (if you wish to continue) seriously limit the scope of what it is you're trying to solve! For example, ANY string is a "part of matching input for `[a-d]+[r-z]*`", since you did not specify a start/end of string matcher!

Comment: ...And what happens if the regex contains backreferences, word boundaries, lookaheads, or some other obscure feature of your chosen regex parser? This problem could get extremely complicated, or even impossible, to solve.

Comment: @TomLord The string I need to decide about is a parameter, as is the regex. I say again, the decision is whether the string can be extended to match the regex, not the other way around. For instance, given the string "aaa" and the regex "[b-d]*", the output would be `false`.

Comment: For a start, the string `"aaa"` DOES match the regex `[b-d]*`, because the regex contains no "start/end of string" boundaries! Thus, literally ANY string matches the regex! But anyway, to illustrate my point, I ask, can the string `"abc"` be extended to match `^ab(b|c)(?=d*\z)\1`? The answer is no, but good luck writing code for every possible regex syntax like this!!

Comment: @TomLord My mistake. And thanks for the sympathy. Now, aside from well-wishing, can you offer some advice?

Comment: If you want to do this as a technical challenge, start with a very simple case of this problem, then build up on it if you want. For example, you could start by only considering regexes containing single characters and repeaters (e.g. `ab*c+d`), and that your input string can only be appended to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can brute-force it this way:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException;

public class RegexSplitter {    
    private static boolean tryRegex(String regex) {
        try {
            Pattern.compile(regex);
            return true;
        } catch(PatternSyntaxException pse) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "[a-d]+[r-z]*";

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();

        int start = 0;
        int end = 1;
        boolean good = false;
        while(end < input.length()) {
            String part = input.substring(start, end);
            if(!tryRegex(part)) {
                if(good) {
                    good = false;
                    results.add(input.substring(start, end - 1));
                    start = end-1;
                }
            } else {
                good = true;
            }
            ++end;
        }
        if(tryRegex(input))
            results.add(input.substring(start,end));

        System.out.println(results);
    }
}

// Output: [[a-d]+, [r-z]*]
```

It's hacky and heuristic, but it may work for your purposes.

Comment: What about the input "rzrz", which DOES match "part of the regex", but will not yield any results from your approach?

Comment: It's not perfect. :)  I understand that [a-z]abcde[f-g]+ will return [a-z]abcde , [f-g]+.  The code above can be refined to handle this case.  I don't know if it needs to depending on the problem Yuval is trying to solve.

Comment: This is the point I am trying to get across in the comments above: That the original problem is impossibly hard unless it is better defined :)

Comment: @DannyDaglas I took your code, fixed it up and it seems to work fine for most cases. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you're asking, but there are several tools out there like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) that you can use to analyze regexes.

[image: RegexBuddy screenshot]

Some languages like Python provide debug modes for regexes:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(r"[a-d]+[r-z]*", re.DEBUG)
max_repeat 1 4294967295
  in
    range (97, 100)
max_repeat 0 4294967295
  in
    range (114, 122)
```

Comment: Does this tool have an API?

Comment: [It does](http://www.regexbuddy.com/integration.html), but I'm not sure whether it exposes this functionality.